# Global function in type library create in C# with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, com, global, typelib

I would like to create a COM type library for use in Excel using C#.  I would like the type library to contain some global functions.  I know, of course, that there are no global functions in C#.  But is there a way to expose a C# class method as a global function in a type library?

Comment: A COM library does not have global functions. It exposes objects and their methods through it's interfaces. Creating a singleton object as suggested by @Yura Zaletsky, and adding functions to it is the closest you will get to having global functions. Note that singletons don't come without problems and may be an obstacle when it comes to unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

I propose you to consider two ways:

1. Consider [singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx) design pattern, which will behave as Global class which after creating will expose to you it's functions
2. Consider static class with static functions.